# Subscription after switchMap does not work

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have created a Confirmation dialog that returns true or false, based on the user's choice.

This is the function that opens the dialog and handles the responses:

```
public action(id: number): void {
    this.dialogService.openDialog(ConfirmationComponent).afterClosed()
        .pipe(
            switchMap(
                (result: boolean) => {
                    if (result) {
                        return this.service.doSomething(id);
                    } else {
                        return of('cancelled');
                    }
                }
            )
        ).subscribe({
            next: (response: string) => {
                this.snackBarService.openSnackBar(response, 'valid');
            },
            error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.httpService.handleError(error);
            },
            complete: () => {
                this.getData();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

When the dialog returns false, the snack-bar opens with the message `cancelled` (as expected) and the `getData()` function gets executed. However, when the dialog returns true, the `doSomething(id)` function gets executed (as expected), but the snack-bar does not show up, and `getData()` is not executed.

Does anybody have any idea why it's behaving like that? I can't figure it out.

Comment: I thought on this for a second after "fixing" the issue by adding a delay and I came to the conclusion that it would be a wiser approach to send the observable as a parameter in the `ConfirmationComponent` and subscribe to it after the user proceeded to do the action. This was a valid approach in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what `this.service.doSomething(id)` returns. I suppose it's an Observable but based on your description it never emits any `next` and no `complete`. It might return an empty Observable such as `EMPTY` or just `new Observable()`.

So the solution here is to make sure that `this.service.doSomething(id);` emits and completes.

Comment: `this.service.doSomething(id)` is an API call that returns an Observable<string>, I tried to log the `response` when the dialog's response was true and it didn't show anything, my best guess is that the `doSomething(id)` doesn't get executed in time and the subscription just ends.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't emit `error` that is suppressed by `this.httpService.handleError(error)`?

Comment: It doesn't. But funny enough, when it does throw an error, the `handleError` gets executed.

Comment: You're not unsubscribing so there's nothing that would cancel the subscription. You can replace `doSomething` with for example `of('response').pipe(delay(1000))` and it should work with longer Observables

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Prior to updating to v16, this was working, but now it doesn't for some reason.